# How to reference a drawable from a unique key

Tags: java, android, dictionary, mapping, drawable

When inflating a fragment, I need to set an `ImageView` drawable using a unique string key that's been passed in from the activity, but that isn't in the form of a R.drawable. Basically I need to map an input string like:

```
"earth" --> R.drawable.icon_earth
"mars" --> R.drawable.icon_mars
"pluto" --> R.drawable.icon_pluto
```

I'm struggling with finding the right way to do this in Android, or even Java in general. Maybe I'm just not searching SO or Google the right way, but I've been stuck on this for over an hour now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about taking a `Map<String, Object>` like this -

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HasMap<String, Object>();
map.put("earth", R.drawable.icon_earth);
```

After that you can get value from the `Map<String, Object>` you have declared - `map` using `map.get("earth")`

Comment: This is how I think I'll end up doing it. The other solutions using `getResources().getIdentifier()` seem easier, but are discouraged in the getIdentifier docs

Answer (score 1):

If you use the string as an icon identifier you can use the [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method of the [Resources](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) class

```
String resourceName = "icon_" + "earth";
int resource = getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", "com.package");
```